# How to use animateWithDuration: when presenting view controller on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation

I'm currently using the following code in order to present my view controller.

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I need to use more complex animation utilizing `UIView animateWithDuration` method. It is just modal presentation and background view controller should stay there. How can I animate presenting view controller's view?

Update: next version of code :)

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL];
RootViewControllerEx *viewController = (RootViewControllerEx *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SB_RDVC"];
viewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
...

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    ...
}
```

VC in storyboard doesn't have any segue specified, it stays lonely in storyboard :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `UIModalPresentationCustom` as your `UIViewController's` `modalPresentationStyle`.

You then need to create a class that conforms to the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and set that your on `presentedViewController`.

Example

```
YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
viewController.delegate = self;
viewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You must then implement the following method:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source;
```

Which returns an object that conforms to a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol, that implements the following method:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIView *inView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIView *toView = [[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey] view];

    toView.frame = //CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    [inView addSubview:toView];
    // Use whatever animateWithDuration you need
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.7f initialSpringVelocity:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
// Custom animation here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // IMPORTANT
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

Always remember to tell the context when a transition is complete, otherwise you'll enter an unstable state.

Comment: Pretty much what I'd just started typing, so I gave up and up voted you instead

Comment: Somehow I get the same animation I always had - appear from bottom. Animation delegate never called. Could it be because I use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and my VC is defined in Storyboard?

Comment: Have you set the presentation style to UIModalPresentationCustom?

Comment: Yes and my class is declared to implement `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol which it does. See update.

Comment: <BooksViewController: 0xba0d330>-><RootViewControllerEx: 0xf0be280> UIModalPresentationCustom presentation style can only be used with an animator or with unanimated presentations.

Comment: `animationControllerForPresentedController:` must return the object that implements the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol, in your case, `self`

Comment: While I'm implementing other delegate methods, it looks like this way is only for iOS 7. My mistake I didn't mentioned iOS 6/7. So now I am not sure if I should modify my question or add new question for iOS 6.

Comment: Custom transitions with UIViewControllers were only introduced in iOS7. Yes, it would have been much more helpful if you stated iOS6 support required clearly

Comment: Anyway, I will open new question for iOS6, sorry. So for iOS7, dismissing view controller works the same way, right?

Comment: Exactly the same way, you can create another delegate for a different animation. Or if you want the default animation, be sure to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationNone`, before dismissing.

Comment: `[inView addSubview:toView]`: where I should remove from view? Does it remove automatically in case of default dismiss action?

Comment: Also how to deal with orientation using this method?

Comment: Orientation goes beyond the scope of this question, but you may need to define different delegates for different orientations.